# Cast 3D geometry as 2D for ogr2ogr GeoJSON

Tags: coordinate-system, geojson, ogr, ogr2ogr, spatialite

I'm trying to take a shapefile that [can be downloaded here](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pvs/21/partnership_shapefiles_19v1_21031.zip) (specifically the shapefile titled `PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031.shp`), convert it from EPSG:4269 to EPSG:3857, and output the GeoJSON into CSV with *only* XY coordinates. Currently, all steps work, except I'm still receiving a trailing 0 coordinate. Here's my command:

`ogr2ogr -f csv -dialect sqlite -t_srs epsg:3857 -sql "select AsGeoJSON(geometry) AS geom, * from PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031" PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031.csv partnership_shapefiles_19v1_21031/PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031.shp -dim 2`

and here's some sample output:

```
{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-83.66666399999999,36.71549199999999,0],
```

How can I drop the trailing 0 coordinate (I assume it's intended to be a Z coord?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can cast your geometry as XY before outputting it to GeoJSON:

> ogr2ogr -f csv -dialect sqlite -t_srs epsg:3857 -sql "select
>   AsGeoJSON(CastToXY(geometry)) AS geom, * from PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031"
>   PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031_2D.csv
>   partnership_shapefiles_19v1_21031/PVS_19_v1_vtd_21031.shp -dim 2

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm   are there reference docs anywhere I can hit up to find options like these that work in ogr2ogr?

Comment: You're welcome. I used this as a reference: http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html

Comment: Is it possible to use CastToXY in a virtual layer in QGIS?